# Variables in jQuery Ajax POST request

Tags: javascript, jquery, post

I'm trying to use jQuery's `$.post()` method with variables from values taken from textboxes on the page. My code looks like this:

```
$.post("install-ajax.php", { host: $("#host").val(), user: $("#user").val(), pass: $("#pass").val(), name: $("#name").val() }, function(data) {

    $("#post").append(data);

});
```

So far, the request hasn't worked at all. Is this possible to do? If so, what do 
I have to do to make it work?

Thanks very much in advance! :)

Comment: Please elaborate on what exactly isn't working...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging from the variables that you want to send via Ajax, I'd suggest trying the following:

```
function construct_vars_from_ids(vars) {
   var obj = {};
   jQuery.each(vars, function(index, el) {
       obj[el] = $('#' + el).val();
   });
   return obj;
}

$.post("install-ajax.php", construct_vars_from_ids(['host', 'user', 'pass', 'name']), function(data) {
   $("#post").append(data);
});
```

Comment: I faced the same problem and thanks for the solution and I want to know why the way that @esqew used is not working